# Error: no se puede dividir por cero

Tags: java

El problema es que me da error cuando lo pruebo varias veces. El error que recibo es que no se puede dividir por cero y ocurre en esta línea:

```
numeroAdvAA = (numeroAdvAux / divisionDigito) % 10;
```

Ésta es la parte del código donde recibo el error:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Entorno:

    int numeroAdivinar;
    int numeroSecreto;
    int numeroAdvAux;
    int numeroSeAux;
    byte contador;
    byte contadorDigito = 0;
    int cifrasAdivinar = 0;
    boolean ganador = false;
    int numeroAdvAA;
    int numeroSeAA;
    int divisionDigito = 10;
    int divisionDigitoAux;
    int contadorDigitoAux = 0;
    int divisionDigitoSec = 10;
    int divisionDigitoSecAux=0;
    //Algoritmo:   
    System.out.println("Turno del Primer Jugador");
    do {
        System.out.println("Introduzca un numero por teclado");
        numeroAdivinar = Leer.datoInt();
    } while (numeroAdivinar <= 0);
    contador = 0;
    numeroAdvAux = numeroAdivinar;
    //Contador de digito
    while (numeroAdvAux != 0) {
        numeroAdvAux = numeroAdvAux / 10;
        contadorDigito++;
    }
    //Para fabricar la division
    for (int i = 0; i < contadorDigito - 1; i++) {
        divisionDigito *= 10;
    }

    divisionDigitoAux = divisionDigito;
    System.out.println("Turno del Segundo Jugador");
    do {
        do {
            System.out.println("Introduzca el segundo numero");
            numeroSecreto = Leer.datoInt();
        } while (numeroSecreto <= 0);
        numeroSeAux = numeroSecreto;
        //Contador de digito
        while (numeroSeAux != 0) {
            numeroSeAux = numeroSeAux/10;
            contadorDigitoAux++;
        }
        //Para fabricar la division
        for (int i = 0; i < contadorDigitoAux - 1; i++) {
            divisionDigitoSec *= 10;
        }

        numeroAdvAux = numeroAdivinar;
        numeroSeAux = numeroSecreto;
        if (numeroAdvAux == numeroSeAux) {

            ganador = true;

        } else {
            divisionDigito = divisionDigitoAux;
            divisionDigitoSecAux=divisionDigitoSec;
            for (int i = 0; i < contadorDigito; i++) {
                divisionDigito = divisionDigito / 10;
                divisionDigitoSecAux=divisionDigitoSecAux/10;
                numeroAdvAA = (numeroAdvAux / divisionDigito) % 10;
                numeroSeAA = (numeroSeAux / divisionDigitoSec) % 10;//Este division digito no es igual al de arriba port eso no lo compara igual debemos hacer otro para este

                if (numeroAdvAA == numeroSeAA) {
                    cifrasAdivinar += 1;
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Has introducido un total de: " + cifrasAdivinar + " digitos bien colocados");
            cifrasAdivinar = 0;

        }

        contador = (byte) (contador + 1);
    } while (contador != 10 && ganador != true);
    if (ganador) {
        System.out.println("Has acertado todas las cifras");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Se te acabaron las oportunidades ");
    }
}
```

Comment: En que linea te da el error.

Comment: intuyo que el problema es porque estas usando enteros y con ellos por ejemplo 9/10 = 0

Comment: Deber de reformular la pregunta para cumplir con las normas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask De todas maneras debes asegurarte que el divisor no es cero, las divisiones por 0 generan excepciones, puedes solucionarlo con un try catch y en el catch por ejemplo mostrar un mensaje de error.

Comment: Con lo que acabas de añadir el error te da porque divisionDigito es 0

Comment: Como puedo plantearlo de otra forma para  no pasar por ese error?

Comment: Depende lo que necesites exactamente.

Answer (score 2):

División digito es un `int` por lo que en esta función `divisionDigito = divisionDigito / 10;` si divisiónDigito es menor que 10 te va a dar como resultado **0,n**, pero al ser una variable de tipo `int`, si tiene decimales el valor se trunca y queda **0**. Tienes que controlar que división digito no sea menor que 10 nunca o hacerlo `double`:

```
double divisionDigito = 10;
```

Comment: Y ahora no me funciona cuando analiza digito a digito cada numero, el problema se ha resuelto perfectamente. Pero no funciona lo otro